# Performing measurement on a function of a waveform in NGSPICE

Tags: measurement, ngspice

I am trying to perform a simple measurement of the absolute value of a waveform (measuring the waveform itself is working). See source file:

```
*First simple simulation
V0 IN 0 PWL ( 0 0 ) ( 5e-9 3) (10e-9 1)
R1 IN 0 500
.TRAN 1P 20N
.MEAS tRAN sample find I(V0) AT=10n
.CONTROL
listing e
destroy all
SAVE V(IN) I(V0)
let abs_cur_vin = abs(i(V0))
RUN
MEAS TRAN sample_abs find abs_cur_vin AT=10n
display
PLOT V(IN)
display
plot I(V0)
.ENDC
.END
```

The error I get is:

```
Error No such vector as abs_cur_vin
```

Thanks.

Comment: is it case-sensitive? i(V0) vs I(V0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the `let` line beneath `RUN` (otherwise there is no information about any current), but above `MEAS`, so that the variable can be used by it:

```
*First simple simulation
V0 IN 0 PWL ( 0 0 ) ( 5e-9 3) (10e-9 1)
R1 IN 0 500
.TRAN 1P 20N
.MEAS tRAN sample find I(V0) AT=10n
.CONTROL
listing e
destroy all
SAVE V(IN) I(V0)
***
RUN
let abs_cur_vin = abs(i(v0))
MEAS TRAN sample_abs find abs_cur_vin AT=10n
***
display
PLOT V(IN)
display
plot I(V0)
.ENDC
.END
```

Now the results for the measurements are shown as:

```
sample              =  -2.000000e-03

sample_abs          =  2.000000e-03
```

Comment: It works.
Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. But if you think this answers your problems, select the answer (the green check mark) so that others, i nthe future, searching for similar problems, will see this question with an accepted answer.

Comment: It is done. Thanks.